# Как создать список с четными числами?

Tags: python

Как создать список в который рандомно будут помещаться 10 четных чисел и после вывести его в консоль

Comment: А список с любыми числами вы создать можете? А в момент создания умножить числа на 2?

Answer (score 0):

у модуля `random` есть разные функции, потратьте 10 минут на то чтобы [ознакомиться](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), это не сложно:

```
from random import randrange

[randrange(0,100,2) for _ in range(10)]
# [86, 74, 32, 36, 60, 62, 46, 76, 86, 36]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 

spisok=[] 

while len(spisok)<10: 
    x = random.randint(0, 100) 
    if x%2==0:     
        spisok.append(x) 

print(spisok)
```